# Алгоритм поиска слогаемых числа

Tags: алгоритм

Здравствуйте, была поставлена задача: необходимо найти слагаемые числа в заданном количестве, таким образом, чтобы один массив слагаемых образовывал максимально доступное число, а второй минимальное. Так же существует ограничение, что слагаемые не могут быть числами больше 9. То есть необходимо разбить входящее число на цифры, сумма которых даст это число, при условии что указанное количество слагаемых всегда будет таким, что из этого количества цифр будет возможно собрать число.

Comment: Вам нужны ВСЕ такие массивы? Если первый попавшийся - то это 12 единиц :)

Comment: Так, извините, я пас, теперь мне совсем ничего не понятно... :( Надеюсь, кто посообразительней найдется.

Comment: но у вас в сумме дается число 13 (1,2,5,5)

Comment: Сначала надо искать слагаемые только из 1, потом из 1 и 2, затем 1,2,3 и так далее до самого числа. Таким образом алгоритм разбивается на более понятные отдельные части. Можно понять каким образом следующий шаг получить из предыдущего.

Comment: @Kasper Дальше нужна Ваша работа.

Comment: *массив цифр, которые могут образовать максимально доступное число и минимально доступное число, для 12 это [93, 39].* Максимальное - это число 111111111111. Оно больше 93 в миллиард с лишним раз. Минимальное -правильное. Но получение таких чисел не требует никаких алгоритмов.

Answer (score 3):

Давайте разберем пару примеров:

Возьмем число 3. Разобьем его на сумму единиц, массив выглядит так `[1,1,1]`. 
Далее переместим последнюю единицу на первом место ( в данном случае перемещение = сложению ), получится `[2,1,0]`, далее сделаем тоже самое со следующей единицей справа, получаем `[3, 0, 0]`. Так мы получили все комбинации цифр, которые в сумме дают 3. Мы не учитываем перестановки `[2, 1, 0]` и `[1, 2, 0]`

Теперь сделаем тоже самое с числом 5, получим такую последовательность массивов.

```
[1,1,1,1,1]
[2,1,1,1,0]
[2,2,1,0,0]
[3,2,0,0,0]
[4,1,0,0,0]
[5,0,0,0,0]
```

Механизм тот же самый за исключением, что когда мы встречаем не 1, то вычитаем из этого числа 1 и переносим вправо ( на самом деле мы тоже самое делаем с 1, поэтому получаются нули в конце массива )

Еще один пример с числом побольше, 8

```
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
[2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]
[2,2,1,1,1,1,0,0]
[2,2,2,1,1,0,0,0]
[2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0]
[3,2,2,1,0,0,0,0]
[3,3,2,0,0,0,0,0]
[4,3,1,0,0,0,0,0]
[4,4,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[5,3,0...]
[6,2,0...]
[7,1,0...]
```

Думаю суть вы уловили: на каждой итерации, мы берем самый крайний правый ненулевой элемент, отнимаем от него единицу и прибавляем к левому элементу, которые тоже считается на итерации

Вот код на js:

```js
const getNumberTerms = (n) => {
  if(!n) return []
  
  const result = [];
  const terms = (new Array(n)).fill(1);
  result.push([...terms]);
  
  let willItterate = true;
  let last = n - 1;
  let current = 0;
  let minCurrent = 0
  while(willItterate) {
    // перемещаем единицу
    terms[current] += 1;
    terms[last] -= 1;
    
    // добавляем массив в результат
    result.push([...terms]);
    
    // если элемент равен 9, то сдвигаем минимально значение курсора вправо
    if(terms[current] === 9) minCurrent++
    
    // сдвигаем правый курсор вправо
    current++;
    // если самый левый элемент равен нулю, то сдвигаем левый курсор в лево
    if(terms[last] === 0) last--;
    
    // если правый курсор зашел на левый, значит, нужно сбросить его на минимальное значение
    if(current >= last) current = minCurrent;
    
    if(last === minCurrent) willItterate = false;
  }
  
  return result;
};

// этот код для презентации
const output = document.getElementById('output');
document.getElementById('input').onchange = function () {
    const result = getNumberTerms(+this.value);
    output.innerHTML = ''
    result.forEach(el => {
      output.innerHTML += `<br>${JSON.stringify(el)}`
    })
}
```

```html
<input id='input'>
<pre id='output'>

</pre>
```

Сложность основного алгоритма, вроде как линейная ( не проверял точно )
Дальше с ответом можно делать, что угодно. Не нравятся 0? Можно убрать их, пройдя циклом ( правда добавится квадратичная сложность ). Нужен массив определенной длины? Допишите нули в конце, либо возьмите первые N элементов

Comment: а как называется данный алгоритм ?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов не знаю, сам придумал его. Ну может название и есть у него

Comment: интересный алгоритм, но не все находит решения, набрал 12, и нету варианта [10,2] и [6,1,1,1,1,1,1] ну и других.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин 10 не может быть по условию, а вот [6,1,1,1,1,1,1] - это да, моя оплошность

Comment: @ThisMan да вижу про 10, толи я невнимательно читал, толи эту информацию потом добавили.